# How does inheritance work in Python metaclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass, python-3.9

Suppose, I have a custom metaclass and a class linked to it:

```
class Meta(type): pass
class A(metaclass=Meta): pass
```

From my understanding that at the end of the `class A` statement, the following steps are executed:

1. Call `Meta('A', (), {})`.
2. Because step 1 is a built-in call, it means that `type.__call__(...)` will be invoked. This is because `type` is linked to the `Meta.__class__`.
3. `type.__call__(...)` in turn run two other methods (a `__new__` and a `__init__`).
4. If `Meta` defined either or both of these methods, then inside of `type.__call__` these methods will be invoked as `Meta.__new__(...)` and/or `Meta.__init__(...)`.
5. class `A` is created and linked to the `Meta` (`A.__class__`).

Now, suppose I have a subclass of `A`:

```
class Meta(type): pass
class A(metaclass=Meta): pass
class B(A): pass
```

At the end of `class B` statement, are the following steps correct?

1. Call `type('B', (), {})` instead of `Meta`, because `B.__class__` is `type`.
2. Invoke `type.__call__(...)` which in turn run two other methods (`__new__` and `__init__`).
3. `type.__new__(type, 'B', (A,), {})`.
4. `type.__init__(cls, 'B', (A,), {})`.

Suppose the above steps is correct (which I doubt), shouldn't `B.__class__` give `type` instead of `Meta`? My reasoning is that `B` is created with default `type` metaclass. But print out `B.__class__` gives `Meta` instead of `type`.

```
print(B.__class__) #<class '__main__.Meta'>
```

Also if I manually create a class with `A` as parent, again the created class is linked to the `Meta`.

```
C = type.__call__(type, 'C', (A,), {})
print(C.__class__) #<class '__main__.Meta'>

#or

D = type.__new__(type, 'D', (A,), {})
print(D.__class__) #<class '__main__.Meta'>
```

My question is how Python create the `class B/C` and how `B/C` is linked to the `Meta`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So --- a somewhat confusing question that can be answered,and somethat simplified
by simply running some examples in the interactive mode.

But to start, when you state:

> `type.__call__(...) in turn run two other methods (a __new__ and a __init__).`

It is a simplification of what takes place.

When we create new  class, like in resolving a class statement `class A:`, `type.__call__` is invoked alright. But is this call is searched in the *class*  of `Meta` itself. That is, the "metaclass" of "Meta" - which by default is `type`.

Bear with me:
When we are talking about an ordinary class E with no custom metaclass, and you create an instance by doing `E()` - Python searches for the `__call__` method in the class of which `E` is an instance: that is, its metaclass. As it is type, then `type.__call__` is called. It is `type.__call__` which calls the `__new__` and `__init__` methods, as you stated, but not only for metaclasses: it orchestrates these calls in any object instantiation - the exact same mechanism is used in any object instantiation in Python: both ordinary objects and classes:

```py
In [178]: class MetaMeta(type): 
     ...:     def __call__(metacls, *args, **kw): 
     ...:         print("Now at the meta-meta class") 
     ...:         return super().__call__(*args, **kw) 
     ...:                         

In [179]: class EmptyMeta(type, metaclass=MetaMeta): 
     ...:     def __call__(cls, *args, **kw): 
     ...:         print("At the metaclass __call__") 
     ...:         return super().__call__(*args, **kw) 
     ...:          
     ...:      
     ...:                         

In [180]: class A(metaclass=EmptyMeta): 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:                         
Now at the meta-meta class

In [181]: a = A()                 
At the metaclass __call__

In [182]: class Direct(metaclass=MetaMeta): pass                     

In [183]: Direct()                
Now at the meta-meta class
Out[183]: <__main__.Direct at 0x7fa66bc72c10>
```

So, in short: when creating a class A, which is an instance of Meta, the `__call__` method of the class of Meta is called. That will call `__init__` and `__new__` in the metaclass Meta. If those are not defined, ordinary attribute lookup will call these methods in the superclass of Meta, which happens to *also* be "type".

Now, moving on on your question: when one inherits from a class with a custom metaclass, like your `B` class, Python takes the most derived metaclass in its superclasses as its own metaclass, not `type`. No need to explicitly declare a custom metaclass. That, in practical means, is what makes metaclass needed instead of just Class decorators: these affect only the class where they are declared, and have no effect in further subclasses.

```py
In [184]: class B(A): pass        
Now at the meta-meta class

In [185]: B()                     
At the metaclass __call__
Out[185]: <__main__.B at 0x7fa6682ab3a0>

In [186]: B.__class__             
Out[186]: __main__.EmptyMeta
```

Even in an explicit call to  `type` instead of the `class` statement, the derived class' metaclass will be the metaclass of the superclass. Note, however, that in this case we are hardcoding the call to the "metameta" class to `type.__new__` and the "custom metaclass of the metaclass" is ignored:

```py
                               
In [187]: C = type("C", (A, ), {})

In [188]: C()                     
At the metaclass __call__
Out[188]: <__main__.C at 0x7fa653cb0d60>
```

If you want to programmaticaly create a class that has a custom "meta meta class" (God forbid one needing this in anything but learning purposes), there is a special call in the `types` module that does that:

```py
In [192]: import types            

In [193]: D = types.new_class("D", (A,), {})                         
Now at the meta-meta class

In [194]: D()                     
At the metaclass __call__
Out[194]: <__main__.D at 0x7fa6682959a0>
```

And to wrap it up, note that if the superclasses of a class have diverging metaclasses, Python will refuse to create a class at all. That is somewhat common in "real world" code, when people try to create Abstract classes (wich usea custom metaclass) with a base class in some framework with an ORM, which typically also have a custom metaclass:

```py
                                                                                                                                         
In [203]: class Meta1(type): pass 

In [204]: class Meta2(type): pass 

In [205]: class A(metaclass=Meta1): pass                             

In [206]: class B(metaclass=Meta2): pass                             

In [207]: class C(A, B): pass     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-1def53cc27f4> in <module>
----> 1 class C(A, B): pass

TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Which is fixable by producing a derived metaclass that inherits from
the metaclasses in both ancestor branches (this requires that both metaclasses
are well behaved, using the `super()` instead of hardcoding calls to `type` - but
that is the case with well maintained and popular frameworks):

```py
In [208]: class Meta3(Meta1, Meta2): pass                            

In [209]: class C(A, B, metaclass=Meta3): pass                       

In [210]:
```

Answer (score 3):

> Call type('B', (), {}) instead of Meta, because B.**class** is type.

As you noted later, it is not.

```py
>>> class Meta(type): pass
...
>>> class A(metaclass=Meta): pass
...
>>> class B(A): pass
...
>>> type(B)
<class '__main__.Meta'>
>>>
```

> My question is how Python create the class B/C and how B/C is linked to the Meta?

If `X` class inherits the `Y` class, then the metaclass of `X` is same with the metaclass of `Y`. You can find detailed information on the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).

From the docs:

> The appropriate metaclass for a class definition is determined as
> follows:
>
> if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then type() is used;
>
> if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of type(),
> then it is used directly as the metaclass;
>
> if an instance of type() is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases
> are defined, then the most derived metaclass is used.
>
> The most derived metaclass is selected from the explicitly specified
> metaclass (if any) and the metaclasses (i.e. type(cls)) of all
> specified base classes. The most derived metaclass is one which is a
> subtype of all of these candidate metaclasses. If none of the
> candidate metaclasses meets that criterion, then the class definition
> will fail with TypeError.